# "Print" to a web service, and pass contextual information

Tags: web-services, printing

**The Problem:**
We have a web-based medical software application that as part of the solution, allows people to upload and share files.  The process of saving, and uploading those files from their source electronic medical record application into ours is cumbersome for the users.

**The Goal:**
I'd like to have a way for them to "print" from the source application, via a standard print dialog (necessary because we can't control the source application), but have that document actually uploaded to our web app either through a web service, or IPP or similar.

**The Complication:**
We also need some contextual data: Which patient does this thing you're printing belong to?  This is done through an identifier which the user would need to specify, and we would match up on our side.

**What I need help with:**
I don't know enough about print drivers, port redirection (e.g. RedMon), or IPP or anything like that to know how this should be architected.  Here's my stab at it.  Will this work?  Is there an easier way?

1. The user installs RedMon or similar and a custom local application we've written to capture the printer image
2. This triggers the local application to prompt the user for the patient information we need to match up the document
3. The local program then authenticates, and uploads the file to our webservice and is available to the user.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your users OS is windows, so a good starting point is **PDFCreator** (a open source virtual printer for windows).

Save your documents as:

- PDF,
- PNG,
- JPEG,
- BMP,
- PCX,
- TIFF,
- PS,
- EPS,
- TXT,
- PSD,
- PCL,
- Raw,
- SVG

to the local filesystem by specifying the location and using a file naming convention. Use the **Action after saving** to run a shell script. Use this shell script to **ask the user for further meta-data** and let this script do the **upload to your web service**.

PDFCreator is open source (you can find it on sourceforge.com) so you are may be able to add some fields for meta data to the printer dialog and passing them by file naming convention to the shell script.

Another option is to collect all uploads in your webapplication and add meta data after upload. May be it is an option to implement a "virtual printer queue" for each user (identified by uploader / author / windows user name / upload from host name).

May be you can start here (not tested):

```
Scripts/RunProgramAfterSaving/FTPUpload.vbs
```

May be interesting, too:

```
Scripts/RunProgramAfterSaving/PopUpMessage.vbs
```

**Note:** Watchout to **not** install adware with the PDFCreator setup.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I should have specified that they can't save the file to their file system.  So this solution wouldn't work in my case.  But it's not a bad solution.